# NSOperations with MagicalRecord - CoreData could not fulfill a fault

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsoperation, magicalrecord

I have an NSOperationQueue that generates cat toys based on a cat's preferences. Operations are defined like this:

```
- (void)main {
    @autoreleasepool {

        self.context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];

        Cat *cat = (Cat*)[self.context objectWithID:self.objectId];

        CatToyMaker *toyMaker = [[CatToyMaker alloc] init];
        [toyMaker toysForPrefs:cat.prefs completion:^(NSDictionary *toys) {
            [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
                cat.toys = toys;
            }];
        }];

    }
}
```

I know this isn't quite right. In fact I get crashes like this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x176338e0 <x-coredata://3FDAE17B-0998-4AB2-B5B8-4F94D6CE9C05/Cat/p226>''
```

What is the correct way to save the toys to the cat Entity in the completion block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

- use a single context only in that operation
- refresh your object references in that context
- save your changes only on that context.

You've got the first two steps right, but your last is saving a different context, and thus is causing problems. Try using this:

```
- (void)main 
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        self.context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];

        Cat *cat = [self.context objectWithID:self.objectId];

        CatToyMaker *toyMaker = [[CatToyMaker alloc] init];
        [toyMaker toysForPrefs:cat.prefs completion:^(NSDictionary *toys) {
            cat.toys = toys;
            [self.context MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
        }];

    }
}
```

Comment: It's ok to use MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait since we're on a background thread right?

Comment: yep. This will eventually call save: with the proper performBlock: setup, and only do this on the  context specified...